# Jasmine: Testing Private Methods in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine

ViewModels in KnockoutJS can contain some public as well as some private methods. 
**public methods**: The ones which are attached to self.**public_method** and can be used to bind with the click from html.

**private methods**: The methods which are defined in View model but not attached to view model and can be used internally only by the public methods. 
Typically defined with function privateMethod(){...}

```
define(['./panel'], function (Panel) {

    'use strict';

    function myPrivateMethod() {...}

    self.myPublicMethod = function() {...}

});
```

While writing the test cases in Jasmine, we can create new instance of the ViewModel and test the public methods normally. But how can we test the private methods.

```
define(['knockout'
], function (ko) {

    'use strict';

    describe('My Private Public Tests', function () {
        var testee;
        testee = new MyViewModel();

it('can test public methods easily', function(){
      // Can be Tested
      expect(testee.myPublicMethod()).toBe(true)
});

// How to Test myPrivateMethod
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Due to the local (private) module variables are scoped in the module definition function. And there is no way to acces them. You can expose additional public methods/variables for testing and mark them like "_someVariable".

Answer (score 0):

**Private methods are not unit testable. Even if you could, I recommend you don't (try to) unit test them directly.** You'll be testing them through the public API of your closures, and if you're not then the code's dead anyways.

If you still feel you *should* be testing those private methods, then that's probably a code smell. **Most likely you're violating the SRP**, and the private methods will have quite a bit of complex logic.

Try to factor those private methods out to something public: static public methods, methods on a new class/closure/function, etc. That new unit will then be unit testable. The old unit can have e.g. a private instance of the new unit. If (creation of) the new unit is sufficiently complex you could even use a factory pattern.

However you supply an instance of the new unit to your existing unit, you can now fake or mock it in your unit tests.

Here's some psuedo code in your context where the existing unit simply asks for a collaborator which publicly exposes the functionality of `myPrivateMethod`:

```
function Collaborator() {
    function myPrivateMethod() {/*...*/}
    this.reasonForExistence = myPrivateMethod; // unit testable
}

function Panel(collaborator) {
    self.myPublicMethod = function() {
       // do stuff
       collaborator.reasonForExistence(); // relay to collaborator
       // do more stuff
    }
}
```

You can supply a fake `collaborator` in your unit tests, use some kind of "Spy" to check that `myPublicMethod` actually *uses* the collaborator if you wish to verify that.

In real scenarios you'll pass a `new Collaborator()` as a dependency.